# When to use a spline vrs a biscuit joiner?

Tags: woodworking, joinery

I know how to do either, but want to know if one is better than the other for particular joints (if so, what cases).

Or is it just a trade off between time / labor (spline) and ease / cost (biscuit joiner)?

In my current case I'm attaching a 3/4 inch lip/edge to a glued up table top (for the top I used leftover unfinished flooring, so that was spline-like).

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a biscuit joiner, then I'd just use that. They're 10x easier than splines, and I'm not convinced that there's any advantage to splines.

There may well be exceptions, depending on your exact circumstances, but since you didn't list any specific circumstances, we don't have anything else to go on.

Something I built with splines: http://www.instructables.com/id/Expandable-formal-dining-table-that-seats-ten-and-/ (see step 12)

Something I built with biscuits: http://www.instructables.com/id/Pantry-Cabinet/

Frankly, I haven't done a spline since I got my biscuit joiner.